# Using a top bar to change language

Tags: language, internationalisation, localization

I'm building a blog with posts in different languages. I'm thinking about doing it like wikipedia, which is :

- On the front page, show a list of languages with at least one post.
- If a post is translated, show a link to each translation.

I'm thinking of adding a **topbar** do redirect users, for instance, that come across the English version when they only speak French :

[image]

My question is two-part :

- Is this a good way to do it or will it annoy users ? (I will remember the user's choice in a cookie)
- How simple is it to find the user's language, based on his browser and/or his IP address ?

Comment: How can users switch language (again) after a language cookie is set?

Comment: They can go back to the front page, or switch through a translation. Also, I'm thinking of not hiding the top bar completely, but leaving a small button at the top of the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a user speaks a certain language when his browser is set to it is tricky. In my experience only after the geo IP lookup resolves to a certain country, it is even acceptable to propose a different language version. Matching this data with browser language settings should improve the confidence, but I don't think this should be relied on without giving a choice.

Keep in mind that Chrome asks to translate foreign sites on default settings, so it would be wise to take steps to disable their topbar if you're going to show yours. You can do so by inserting this code to the `head` section of the website:

```
<meta name="google" value="notranslate" />
```

Comment: Great point about chrome.

Comment: I won't force anything to the user, but I also don't want to lose people who stumble upon the wrong version.

Comment: I would also consider proposing a different language based on the `Accept-Language` request header.  Use a `Content-Language` response header to assist search engines.

Comment: @Brian I've been reading up about `Accept-Language` to answer that question, and my general deduction was that it's not to be relied on, because very few people have that configured properly. Just look at the [w3's guide](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-lang-priorities.en.php#changing). The sole fact that it's set automatically to match system defaults and it's more of an _Under the Bonnet_ setting (Chrome instructions) makes it much less important in my view.

Comment: @fwr: IE7+ checks the system Locale, Safari checks the system language.  So, that already means that you'll receive a useful `Accept-Language` pretty often.  You can't *rely* on it, but if `Accept-Language` is not English, there is a high probability that it is accurate.  That's enough to justify bugging a user once (and then remembering not to bug them again).